# Should OEIS links be updated?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

Historic links to the OEIS are of the form http://www.research.att.com/~njas/sequences/A097048. These links no longer work: Neil has retired from AT&T, and in the meantime has set up the [OEIS foundation](http://oeisf.org). The working form these days is http://oeis.org/A097048.

Should the old-form links be changed by some automated process, or should it be left to individuals to update their links as they find them? I don't know if there's a generic policy for broken links, and I don't know, even if there is one, if the same logic should apply to the general case as to this one - an important resource for which the link pattern has changed in a predictable (and hopefully final) manner.

(I noted this when revisiting the comments for [What's the simplest rational not expressible as a sum of a given number of unit fractions?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/33628), but I assume there are numerous similar references on mathoverflow.)

Hugo van der Sanden

Comment: The example you point out is in a comment (of mine), and my understanding is that only moderators can edit comments.

Comment: Could Stack Exchange staff have these all automatically fixed?

Comment: I think that when we moved to 2.0 we gained the power to edit our own comments. Not sure if we can edit old comments of ours from before the migration, though. At least, I can't see how to do it.

Comment: @David: Nonmoderators can only edit comments within 5 minutes of posting them.

Comment: Okay, good to know. Thanks

Comment: To find posts and comments respectively that point to the old address, see   https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1543589/posts-that-link-to-the-oeiss-old-url https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/1543626/comments-that-link-to-the-oeiss-old-url

Answer (score 17, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)

---

For reference, here are the pages that Google knows use the old domain.

If people have strong feelings, they can fix those they want to and remove them from this list. For comments, a follow-up comment pointing out the new url will probably be sufficient.

---

## Done

<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/28601/</s>

<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/6408/</s>

<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/30370/</s>

<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/18639/ (and comment [Number of invertible {0,1} real matrices?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/18636/#comment-35967))</s>

<del>[Can you find linear recurrence relation for dimensions of invariant tensors?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/17610/)</del>

<strike>https://mathoverflow.net/a/141608/</strike>

<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/27550/</s>

<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/44247/</s>   <s>(and comment [Count of lattices on finite set](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44242/#comment105579_44242))</s>

<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/42982/</s>

<strike>https://mathoverflow.net/a/29179/</strike> 
<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/39134/</s>

<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/39459/</s>

<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/43361/</s>

<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/8503/</s>

<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/8086/</s>

<s>[Number of non-Abelian groups of order $2^n$](https://mathoverflow.net/q/30358/)</s> <s>(and comment, [Number of non-Abelian groups of order $2^n$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/30358/#comment67357_30367))</s>

<strike>https://mathoverflow.net/a/28488/</strike>

<strike>https://mathoverflow.net/a/40421/</strike> <s>(plus comment [number of partial orders modulo a fixed number](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40390/#comment95011_40390))</s>

<strike>[How good is Kamenetsky's formula for the number of digits in n-factorial?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/19170/)</strike> 


<strike>https://mathoverflow.net/a/35693/</strike>

 <strike>https://mathoverflow.net/a/27017/</strike>

<strike>https://mathoverflow.net/a/44553/</strike>

<strike>[Describe a tree by junctions](https://mathoverflow.net/q/15514/)</strike>

<s>[A binomial generalization of the FLT: Bombieri's Napkin Problem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/27305/)</s> (and <s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/27425/4177</s>)

<s>[Can a positive binary quadratic form represent 14 consecutive numbers?](https://mathoverflow.net/q/23943/)</s>

<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/6389/</s>

<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/30371</s>

<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/26639/</s>

<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/44194/</s> <s>(plus comment [How many simply connected subsets of an n-by-m grid?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/44162/#comment105458_44162))</s>

<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/29587/</s>

<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/16405/</s>

#### Not OEIS, but still links to Slaone's AT & T homepage

<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/78938/</s>

<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/24865/</s>

<s>https://mathoverflow.net/a/9687/</s>

#### Same, but in commeants

<s>[Prove: if a1,...,an are uniformly distributed unit vectors, then a1*a1'+...+an*an'=n/2*I](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/54342/#comment135667_54345) (should be to http://neilsloane.com/sphdesigns/)
[How small can a sum of a few roots of unity be?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/46068/#comment110746_46069) (should be to http://neilsloane.com/doc/1218anti.ps)</s>

[Covering a unit ball with balls half the radius](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98007/#comment252723_98217) (should be to http://neilsloane.com/coverings/)

[Root systems and sums of squares](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40624/#comment95696_40649) (should to http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/E6.html, http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/E7.html and http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/E8.b.html)

[What is the largest possible thirteenth kissing sphere?](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/94739/#comment243241_94752) (should be to http://neilsloane.com/packings/index.html)

Comment: Feeling obsessive compulsive, I did most of the comments.

Comment: You think you were obsessive-compulsive? I used the 'share' link on each question/answer to get the above list, manually (and trimmed the comments to links to short-form) ... ^_^

Comment: And I moved the others under the correct heading (wasn't looking close enough when I pasted those ones in).

Comment: @Scott more for you...

Comment: Thanks for the list - I'd guessed there would be more, but for these numbers I guess hand-editing is fine (accepting some "omg, something changed" front-page churn).

Comment: The striked ones are flooding the list? Could I remove them?.

Comment: I moved the struck out ones down the page. @ScottMorrison - there are still four comments that need editing, if you feel so inclined.

Comment: @DImension10AbhimanyuPS - I changed the WayBack machine links that you inserted to arxiv/neilsloane.com links.

Comment: I also tracked down the other links to non-OEIS pages that need to be inserted into comments.

Comment: @ScottMorrison - thanks!

Comment: I found one of my questions with a link to Sloane's AT&T page that was not listed above.  http://mathoverflow.net/questions/18636/number-of-invertible-0-1-real-matrices  I edited it in.  Can someone explain how they are searching for the culprits?

Comment: @Tony Huynh: I fixed the answer, but there is still a comment. A pure speculation, but one reason the search might have missed it is that the link didn’t use markdown syntax, but HTML `<a>...</a>`. If so, there may be more such cases.

Comment: @TonyHuynh I used Google and merely searched for the domain to which Sloane's page was attached - Emil is right in that I wouldn't have found instances where the link was coded in HTML.

Comment: @EmilJeřábek Yes, I suspect there are indeed many more cases where HTML was used.  I will try to fix any that I come across.

Comment: @DavidRoberts Thanks for confirming Emil's speculation.

Comment: You can probably get Scott Morrison's help to make an SQL query on the data explorer to find most occurrences.  Gerhard "Or Grep A Database Dump" Paseman, 2013.10.30

Comment: "Grep a database dump" sounds vaguely sinister, or at the very least quite unsanitary.

Comment: @ScottMorrison: A quick google search using the term `site:mathoverflow.net njas` still seems to give *comments* whose links are broken e.g. http://mathoverflow.net/q/36188/16302 and http://mathoverflow.net/q/16780/16302.

Comment: Just for the record, it is easy to find posts with links to a given domain using the built-in search: https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3A%22%2Aresearch.att.com%2A%22. For comments you have to use SEDE: https://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/556789/comments-containing-given-keyword-with-text-and-author?Word=research.att.com. Currently there are 56 posts and 39 comments. (Of course, not necessarily all of them are links to OEIS. You can restrict the searches by including also `~njas/sequences`.)

Comment: I left a bit more detailed info (some other queries, dead links to other domains) in chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10243/conversation/outdated-oeis-links and https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/10243/2019/6/26

Comment: BTW it seems rather unusual to me that this is marked (status-completed) when there is plenty of posts (and comments) on the main site with the old domain.