# Bumping of obviously offtopic questions

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Today, https://mathoverflow.net/questions/28487/is-there-a-concept-equivalent-to-factorial-that-uses-addition-rather-than-multip was on the front page. I was about to flag the question, only to realise that the question was already closed and three years old.

I think it was due to an edit adding a tag. I do not see any reason why the tag should be added, and bumping these questions seems like a bad use of the site. Maybe I am wrong, and there is a good reason why the question should be retagged. Anyway, I thought it was good to have a short discussion on this.

Comment: The revision histories show precisely why a thread was bumped. In this case it was due to updating a broken link in an answer (see http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1099/should-oeis-links-be-updated for context) **not** for tagging. [Fixing of tags was also done but **only** because the question was on top anyway.] Whether one should fix the link in this thread might still be debatable but as it is part of fixing some general problem it seems alright.

Comment: I think that question can be safely deleted.  Anyone against?

Comment: @S.Carnahan I have nothing against it. It has a surprisingly large number of views though (15k). Maybe this hints at some significance of it to someone/somewhere.

Comment: It is the top Google hit (on my computer) for the terms "factorial" and "addition".  The next hit is an xkcd forum that covers the exact same topic, so I think our version of the discussion is redundant.

Comment: @quid: I was a bit too quick. I only looked at the edit history of the question, not of the answers. I wouldn't have posted otherwise.

Comment: A related recent post: [Restriction on editing closed questions](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/3832).